# A crash with +[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:]

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

My app crashes with the following callstack several times per day in thousands of sessions:

```
Thread 28 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   abort + 140
2   libsystem_malloc.dylib              _nano_vet_and_size_of_live + 0
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib              nano_realloc + 648
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib              malloc_zone_realloc + 180
5   CoreFoundation                      __CFStringCreateImmutableFunnel3 + 692
6   CoreFoundation                      _CFStringCreateWithBytesNoCopy + 44
7   Foundation                          -[NSString initWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:] + 128
8   Foundation                          +[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:encoding:error:] + 68
9   TheApp                              +[LSEmotionManager arrayFromTxtFile:] (LSEmotionManager.m:58)
```

And the following is the code:

```
+ (NSArray *)arrayFromTxtFile:(NSString *)name
{
    NSString *emojiResourceBundleName = kEmojiReourceBundleName;

    NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
    NSString *bundlePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", emojiResourceBundleName]];
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
    NSString *file = [bundle pathForResource:name ofType:@"txt"];
    if (!file) {
        bundlePath = [resourcePath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@", emojiResourceBundleName]];
        bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithPath:bundlePath];
        file = [bundle pathForResource:name ofType:@"txt"];
    }

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    NSArray *array = [string componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

    return array;
}
```

It's really a little strange to me. I have tried even if the file object is nil, the app should not crash. And I have checked, my resource file is in UTF-8 encoding. Is there anything else I have missed?

Comment: Is this a random crash or can you reproduce it every time ?

Comment: `NSString *string = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];` using the `error` parameter could give a hint.

Comment: It's a random crash 1-2 times in thousands of sessions.

Comment: With always the same file?

Comment: You are not alone: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/63546